# Converting an XPI file so I can read

Tags: firefox-addon, xpi

A little background on my problem...

I play an online text RPG I will keep the name to myself as I dont want to pull people away from this community for another..... but that is off topic.

In our game, programmers come and go, quite frequently and they leave behind a legacy of programs that serve the community in the simplest of ways.

**My question is, How do I open a XPI file and fix coding issues that are no longer relevant? How do I open a file and read it so that it is not in "Wingding**"

**What programs can i use to de bunk the issues that I will share below?**

Sample of what I see when I open the file in notepad++; which is what every firefox add-on site has told me to use....

```
    PK    ¡>†¡mŠ       install.rdf”[s¢0ÇŸÛ™~Æ¾íE[u¬]Ðj-Òz©®ö-@€    ´`DÛÙï¾:E·ÝÙ¼0œóÿÎ…“Öí&„5¤|S*KJé¶}qÞšt{BêÁì¦äs5e9I)Q%B=¹Üh4d¥"W*"u\‘m1³ËRÎ4ax„…äÈØŠ¢TeîÀËRú¥‹s!=­.d6EO³€Eb~SŠ)nîÉ&ÂŒƒ C€‘ß‘Âþ´`ØDNû)æ    £ f?-Š<ŸÃH6   [rî?0aÉD™íX¶oL[‘*’’‰–‹ó³³Â¦pBÛÐ$™ÿð¾óç‚9EV¼3>û€—ûñ6W_ª‡i>S€0ÿ?ùÔIB/ôÅ¢œÏ^·ï°°
Cˆ9\BîC!ï‹`Q’0H/ÍCÊbÉã˜>    a<8›Û…ÉMBÎb•‡&Æ‘ø¿Y’È$K+JÇ%ç€”þDYÌOþ8«ÜnÀmÛô]SSúéª?Xjw|§kã™¦UûZ·££±¡{ãnù°ˆ¼å|9±µ vlÏ7ß´àI›ãûZä¾ô‚`€ëvÌ¬Å½æ^‡QïÙñ:á6ê˜³»÷7dÆúk]®)#Ã Kuô‚x2ZÌ{3E,7áÄBúkÔ™ù`¼ùCÝ¸~Ö™3])+R«q45ÊÜ\÷-ïêöôÇûÎÊÁÈpØÊ)ÏëldŽüÅº‚f]-tµ±¦Êß•yØ§C8 äZÈ'c;Ý»Waµ> ]WTÅ½íŠÄêUÕ–Å²
TÐ€kµ^ýý÷¢Ã„Ï÷«sX¥‚él‚ªô#g>M'•È_—’QßµájÉé½—>ÿ PK
 ±Å:               chrome/PK
 ”9¬<               chrome/content/PK    
º“>¯ /}Ÿ  W8     chrome/content/browser.xul½[yoÛ8ÿ»Ìwàxi
Ôñ!ŸM2ƒØiÒ™6m¶ö´;
Z¢%Ö©¥¨8Î§ßGJv|2¬“6@“”~ïä;(ùø÷Û˜¡"S*øI©vX-ýþÛÏ?ÿrö¡?üûê5°Æð
þ__¢’I“W•
```

I know this may mean nothing and if it does just please respect my question and dont negatively rate it because of my lack of knowledge about this topic...

What this add-on is, is a raid bar, that organizes accounts into "bookmarks" as an accessible and ready to join raids while retaining the link of the raid in the browser to reduce steps in the process of raiding.

The owner of the add-on is not me.... it is not logical to track down the person that made it because it was crafted over 10 years ago and the means of getting in touch with the person are not reliable anymore.

I dont want to take his add-on and claim it as my own.... I want to update it and carry on what he started as a respect for the player and programmers that have come and gone from the outwar community

Thank you for your time

Comment: That's probably a ZIP file.

Comment: All i do is drag and drop the file into firefox and it downloads it.... It works in some ways.... but the program is out of touch with how the game has evolved

Comment: when I try and read it with anything else it goes nuts

Comment: Yes, its a zip file. Based on the output you had provided it looks like a very old addon which uses `xul`. The `xul` based add-ons will be deprecated sooner in Firefox. So, it would be a wise thought to take the logic from the addon and implement is using [`webextensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

Comment: how do I get it to a point that I can read it though.... that is what I need help with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename it from `.xpi` to `.zip` then you can open it and extract the contents. Do look into WebExtensions API though, as old XUL addons are going away by the end of 2017, you seem to have an overlay there. You can read more here - https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/

Webextensions here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/